# canvas toDataUrl to facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello guys i'm having an issue to post image canvas to facebook.

here is my function i'm using. i'm able to download the image using another function, but whenever i try to share the image to facebook it always give me error .

```
        share.off('click').click(function(){
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
FB.init(
{
    appId : ******
});

  FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
        message:'photo description',
        url: canvasData      
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    }); 
    }).fadeIn();
    }
```

if i changed `url: canvasData` to an actual image link it will be successful. any workaround to make that possible? 
thanks in advance

Comment: your `canvas.toDataUrl` data contains encoding information: `data:image/png;base64...` Have you tried stripping that away before the `POST` ? See [this post](http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/file-uploading-over-ajax-using-html5)—scroll down to "Server Side"

Comment: and how do i get back the image after i encode it ? @couzzi

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api("/me/photos","POST",
{
    "source": "{image-data}"
},
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
});
```